# mapping of data members in a class

Tags: c++, class, oop, stl

I want to store the roll and score of the students in a map in the sorted order of roll and also retrieve the score for a given roll. The student information are to be stored in a class. I referred to a no. of past stack overflow posts where mapping of data members was explained but they were not specific.

following is my class design but now I am clueless how to link the student class with the student_map class,I have tried this but the compiler says that no match for ‘operator<< in line: cout<<(*it).first<<" "<<(*it).second please help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
    int roll;
    float score;
    public:
        Student(int r=0)
        {
            roll=r;
        }
        Student(float s=0.0)
        {
            //roll=r;
            score=s;
        }
        bool operator <(Student s)
        {
            if(roll<s.roll)
                return true;
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
            
        }
        friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &, Student &); 
};
ostream & operator << (ostream & out,Student & s)
{
    out<<s.roll<<endl;
    out<<s.score<<endl;
    return out;
}
class Student_map
{
    map<Student,Student>stu;
    public:

        void insert_data(int n,float f)
        {
            
            stu.insert(map<Student,Student>::value_type(n,f));
        }
        void display()
        {
            map<Student,Student>::iterator it;
            for(it=stu.begin();it!=stu.end();it++)
               cout<<(*it).first<<" "<<(*it).second;
        }

};
int main()
{
    Student_map stm;
    stm.insert_data(45,100.00);
    stm.insert_data(12,50.7);
    stm.insert_data(80,50.9);
    stm.display();
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is hard to follow, and looks like you, yourself, don't seem to fully understand the requirements of the program you're trying to write. The only one who can help you figure that out would be your teacher or instructor, or whoever gave you this programming assignment. It's very unlikely that anyone here has the same teacher or instructor, and the same assignment, and knows what it requires you to do, and who can help you clarify the requirements.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have made some edits in the code,to make it more understandable

Comment: I don't remember saying anything about the shown code. I'm pretty sure that I wrote that the explanation, and not the code, is hard to follow. And I still don't have the same teacher or instructor, or the same assignment, and would have any idea what it requires anyone to do. The only one who can help you explain the requirements of your program is whoever gave you this assignment.

Comment: You say you get a lot of errors. Please show those error messages.

Comment: We're missing info. But in case it helps, `stu` is of type `map<int, Student>`, meaning it maps integers to students. `map<int, Student>::valueType`, then, is of type `pair<const int, Student>`. Yet you try to construct a value type by supplying `(n, f)`, where n is an integer, and f is a float. In other words, your map is from integer to student, but you're treating it as if it's a mapping from integer to float. If `f` was a student object, or if a student could be constructed from a float, then it would make more sense. There may be other errors too; this just caught my eye immediately.

Comment: @Nerdizzle yes exactly I changed that just now and made it into map<Student,Student> but still the compiler says that  no match for ‘operator<< in line:  cout<<(*it).first<<" "<<(*it).second

Answer (score 0):

This might be an XY problem, but without more context I can't say for sure, so I suppose I'll just explain how to get rid of the compiler errors (though I highly suggest you think carefully about the task you've been assigned and make sure that you're solving it in a reasonable way).

In order to use a user-defined type as a key in a `std::map`, you must define a `<` operator for comparing two `const` keys. It *must* be defined to compare `const` keys because keys in a map *must* be constant (if a key changed, how would you inform the map? How would it rearrange its data to accommodate the key change?).

You have not done this. You have only provided a `<` operator for comparing two keys, *not* two `const` keys. Fix this like so:

```
bool operator <(const Student& s) const {
    ... // Your implementation here
}
```

Notice that the function is marked as `const`, meaning it operates on a `const Student`, and the parameter type is also `const Student`; thus it compares two `const Student` objects. I also made the parameter an lvalue reference; it's already a constant anyways, so why not? There's no use in introducing unneeded copy and move constructions.

Secondly, the `<<` operator is not working for the same reason. `(*it).first` is a `const Student`, and so you must define an operator for outputting a `const Student`:

```
friend ostream & operator <<(ostream &, const Student &);
...
ostream & operator << (ostream & out,const Student & s)
{
    ... // Your implementation here
}
```